# Show image in Excel using VBA from rest is not showing any image

Tags: excel, vba, image, rest, msxml2

I am trying to insert an image from a request and it is not showing any image.
Here is my VBA code

```vb
Sub InsertPicFromURL()
    Dim myUrl As String                         ' path of pic
    Dim myPicture As Picture                    ' embedded pic
    Dim response As String                      ' create string to receive image in text format
    Dim request As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60         ' Create the object that will make the webpage request.
    
    myUrl = "https://syncmediaapi-int.saphety.com/WCFSyncMediaWS.svc/rest/GetMediaContentByUrlId/6241bd8f-fbf0-4d53-844e-c8186aafeb05/"
    
    request.Open "GET", myUrl, False                      ' Where to go
    request.send                                          ' Send the request for the webpage.
    response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)   ' Get the webpage response text into response variable.
    Set myPicture = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(response) 'put image into cell
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem or issue? I think you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Hi @BigBen.
 It is not  showing the image. The value in **response** is "‰PNG
 
   
IHDR   ¨   j     ñ Cµ  ÿÿIDATxÚì œUÕµÆÏ¹m 30 ½Hï½# (MEE}ö®±F šX_^Lì-vM4‰½E lØP°Ð ”Þ{ †6 0å–óþç,îrsg   #„³~fr¹÷œ½×Þ{­okWÛq Ë _|ñåp Û >_|ñåp  ø|ñÅ—ÃN|àóÅ _ ;ñÏ _|9ìÄ >_|ñå°  ø|ñÅ—ÃN|àóÅ _ ;ñÏ _|9ìÄ >_|ñå°  ø|ñÅ—ÃN|àóÅ _ ;ñÏ _|9ìÄ ¾x< "

Comment: Thanks BigBen. I updated it.

Comment: Your GET request returns an actual image, not the path to an image.  You need to save the image to local disk and then insert it from there.

Comment: ...or you can insert it directly from the URL.

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams, thanks for your help. I understood your idea but I don´t know how to do it. Is it possible to share any implementation idea?

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams, thanks for your help. I understood your idea and tried to solve. The result is not okay because the image is damage.

Comment: ```VBA```
Dim myU As String
Dim myP As Picture
Dim MyI As String
Dim req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim myF As String
Dim datim As String
datim=Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss")
myF=Application.DefaultFilePath & "\SC" & datim & ".PNG"
myU="https://syncmediaapi-int.saphety.com/WCFSyncMediaWS.svc/rest/GetMediaContentByUrlId/6241bd8f-fbf0-4d53-844e-c8186aafeb05/"
req.Open "GET", myU, False
req.send
MyI=StrConv(req.responseBody, vbUnicode)
Open myF For Output As #1
Write #1, MyI
Close #1
Set myP = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(myF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub InsertPicFromURL()
    Dim imgPath As String, myPicture
    
    imgPath = GetImagefile("https://syncmediaapi-int.saphety.com/WCFSyncMediaWS.svc/rest/GetMediaContentByUrlId/6241bd8f-fbf0-4d53-844e-c8186aafeb05/")
    Debug.Print imgPath
    Set myPicture = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(imgPath)
    
End Sub

Function GetImagefile(url As String) As String
    Dim request As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, strm As Object, pth As String
    Set strm = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    request.Open "GET", url, False
    request.send
    pth = TempPath()
    strm.Type = adTypeBinary
    strm.Open
    strm.Write request.responseBody
    strm.SaveToFile pth
    strm.Close
    GetImagefile = pth
End Function

Function TempPath() As String
    With CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        TempPath = .buildpath(.getspecialfolder(2), .gettempname())
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.
Here the corrected version:

```
Sub InsertPicFromURL()
    Dim myUrl As String         ' path of image
    Dim myPicture As Picture    ' embedded image
    Dim MyImage As String       ' create string to receive image in text format
    Dim request As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60  ' Create the object that will make the webpage request.
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim datim As String
    datim = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss") 'datetime to generate file
    myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\SC" & datim & ".PNG"
    myUrl = "https://syncmediaapi-int.saphety.com/WCFSyncMediaWS.svc/rest/GetMediaContentByUrlId/6241bd8f-fbf0-4d53-844e-c8186aafeb05/"
    request.Open "GET", myUrl, False         ' Where to get image
    request.send                             ' Send the request for the webpage.
    MyImage = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)  ' Get the webpage response text into response variable.
    Open myFile For Output As #1  'open file to save image
    Print #1, MyImage             'write to file
    Close #1                      'close file
    Set myPicture = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(myFile) 'put image into cell
End Sub
```